# Scrape multiple domains with axios, cheerio and handlebars on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, handlebars.js, cheerio

I am trying to make a webscraper, that outputs certain data from node js into the javascript, or html file im working on. Its important that the data of multiple sub pages can be scraped (that I have no code access to) and be displayed in the same html or js file. The problem is that I cant output the results I get from the axios function into global. If i could my problem would be solved.

So far I have been trying to use axios to get the data I need and cheerio to modify it. I created a const named "articles" where I pushed in every title I needed from the website im scraping.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const hbs = require('hbs')


const url = 'https://www.google.com/'
const articles = []

axios(url)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        
        $('.sprite', html).parent().children('a').each(function() {
            const text = $(this).attr('title')
        
            articles.push({
                text
            })       
        })
         console.log(articles)
     
        const finalArray = articles.map(a => a.text);
        console.log(finalArray)
        
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

That works well so far. If I ouput the finalArray I get the array I want to. But once im outside of the axios function the array is empty. Only way it worked for me is when I put the following code inside the axios function, but in this case I wont be able to scrape multiple websides.

```
console.log(finalArray) //outputs empty array

// with this function I want to get the array displayed in my home.hbs file.
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
            res.render('views/home', {
               array: finalArray
            })
        })
```

Basicly all I need is to get the finalArray into global so I can use it in the app.get function to render the Website with the scraped data.

Comment: `finalArray` is local to the `.then` handler attached to the axios call, as it is declared with `const`. If you want it to be global, you would need to declare it in the global scope, just as you are doing with `articles`.

Comment: It doesn't work. Even if i want to console.log(articles) outside the axios function i get an empty array.

Comment: Are you trying to re-run the axios call on every incoming request to `/` on your server, or do you want to run it one time when the app starts and serve the same data repeatedly?

Comment: When I load the Google page I don't see any `.sprite` in the HTML. That could be why your array is empty.

Comment: Google is just a placeholder, im using a different website.

Comment: I don't really know too much about servers i just want the data to be drawn once from the third party websites. Then this data shall be loaded into my website. The code i wrote is far from being finished. I need multiple axios functions to scrape multiple websites and have their data displayed on my website. Thats why I need to get this function out of axios into global.

Comment: It does work. But you can't log `finalArray` _before_ the axios call has got the response and expect `articles` or `finalArray` to have been populated. You need to log these within the `app.get` handler for `/`. There is a race-condition here because it is possible to request your `/` page _before_ the axios `.then` handler is executed, but I don't think this will be an issue for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases here. Either you want to re-run your scraping code on each request, or you want to run the scraping code once when the app starts and re-use the cached result.

New request per request:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const express = require("express");

const scrape = () =>
  axios
    .get("https://www.example.com")
    .then(({data}) => cheerio.load(data)("h1").text());

express()
  .get("/", (req, res) => {
    scrape().then(text => res.json({text}));
  })
  .listen(3000);
```

Up-front, one-off request:

```js
const scrapingResultP = axios
  .get("https://www.example.com")
  .then(({data}) => cheerio.load(data)("h1").text());

express()
  .get("/", (req, res) => {
    scrapingResultP.then(text => res.json({text}));
  })
  .listen(3000);
```

Result:

```bash
$ curl localhost:3000
{"text":"Example Domain"}
```

It's also possible to do a one-off request without a callback or promise that uses a race condition to populate a variable in scope of the request handlers as well as the scraping response handler. Realistically, the server should be up by the time the request resolves, though, so it's common to see this:

```js
let result;
axios
  .get("https://www.example.com")
  .then(({data}) => (result = cheerio.load(data)("h1").text()));

express()
  .get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({text: result});
  })
  .listen(3000);
```

Eliminating the race by chaining your Express routes and listener from the axios response handler:

```js
axios.get("https://www.example.com").then(({data}) => {
  const text = cheerio.load(data)("h1").text();
  express()
    .get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.json({text});
    })
    .listen(3000);
});
```

If you have multiple requests you need to complete before you start the server, try `Promise.all`. Top-level `await` or an async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) can work too.

Error handling has been left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved. I used this code, instead of the normal axios.get(url) function:

```
axios.all(urls.map((endpoint) => axios.get(endpoint))).then(

axios.spread(({data:user}, {data:repos}) => {
```

with "user", and "repos" I am now able to enter both URL data and can execute code regarding the URL i like to chose in that one function.